# Populate a table using COPY into an extension?

Tags: postgresql

I have doing an extension in Postgres.
For do that, I make a backup in plain text of my functions, types, etc and I use this file for my extension.

Now I want to add an auxiliar table too. But the dump in the file for the table is like that (after it has create the table "tAcero" and the sequence):

```
COPY sdmed."tAcero" (id, area, masa, tipo, tamanno) FROM stdin;
44  65.30   502.000 HEB 180
45  78.10   601.000 HEB 200
.....
more values
\.
```

and I wonder if could be possible to use this COPY statement for populate the table into the extension, or I only can do it using "INSERT"?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed load tables in PostgreSQL using the COPY statement.

An example using the psql client and a CSV file:

```
CREATE TABLE test_of_copy (my_column text);

\COPY test_of_copy FROM './a_file_stored_locally' CSV HEADER;
```

Where the contents of `a_file_stored_locally` are:

```
my_column
"test_input"
```

Please have a read of the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html. If you have any issues with this, perhaps add some more detail to your question.

Comment: Thank you. But my question is if is posible to do that into a extension file. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/extend-extensions.html